# Problem using csvsimple with tab-delimited file

Tags: csvsimple

#### The problem

I am having a problem reading tab-delimited files using csv-simple. My question is how do I fix it, and why is it occuring in the first place

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[centering,margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
abc def
fgh ijk
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2cm}\=\hspace*{2.5cm}\= \kill
\csvreader[head=false,separator=tab]{\jobname.csv}{1=\word,2=\meaning}{\word \> \meaning\\}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

#### Problem

```
! Undefined control sequence.                                                                            
\meaning ->\csvcolii
```

#### Update 1

So it was suggested that `filecontents*` does not preserve tabs. So I created a separate file with tabs, and updated my code.

Both of them are here: https://gist.github.com/deepakjois/7d70ef87b061c97f91e9

Now I am getting a really funny output, where the second column of the first row is repeating for all the rows.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think `\meaning` is a reserved LaTeX command. Shows you the content of a macro.

Comment: Note that `filecontents*` doesn't output tab characters.

Comment: @egreg You may be right. I edited the file and inserted my own tab character, but I am having some other problem. Let me update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `\meaning` because it's a reserved command to print out a macros command, for example `\meaning\csvreader`.

I just can recommend you to *always* use individual prefixes for your macros.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[centering,margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\csvreader[tabbing, no head, separator=tab, table head=\hspace*{5cm}\=\hspace*{5cm}\=\kill]{\jobname.csv}{1=\mycsvword,2=\mycsvmeaning}{\mycsvword \> \mycsvmeaning\\}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem

Comment: I tried substituting `\meaning` to `\mycsvmean`, but it still does not work. Still gives the same error: `! Undefined control sequence.\mycsvmean ->\csvcolii`

Comment: did u try it with my MWE? because it's working...

Comment: I can confirm that your answer is working on my system.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I get the same as vyom (see the update).

Comment: @egreg I used the code from musicman and the data file with tabs. I compiled with pdflatex and xelatex without problems. My system is a Windows PC with MiKTeX, if that is causing the difference to your results (?).

Comment: @musicman I did not notice the change in the MWE, sorry. I just tried it and it works. However, I would still like to find out why my example does not work (see updated MWE in my question). Whatever the problem, it does not seem related to `\meaning`.